# How to get a list from all work items from a specific board in TFS API without ID?

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using TFS and I would like to get all work items from a specific board. This is how I'm getting the board atm: `https://myTFSLink.com/tfs/TPC/ProjectName/MY-BOARD-NAME/_apis/work/boards?api-version=5.1`

But nothing about stories/workItems are present in this API request. I know I can get all workItemsRevisions using

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?api-version=5.0
```

but I don't know how I can target this to a specific board :(

I also know that I can get multiple workItems by ID with

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=297,299,300&$expand=all&api-version=5.1
```

but the ideal would be get all workItems from a specific board as I said in the beginning. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A specific board is corresponding to a Team/Area Path, so you can try to [query the work items By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). For example,

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1

Request Body:

{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'PRODUCT BACKLOG ITEM' AND [Area Path] = 'TestCase\\Team1' order by [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```